# How to skip the space in the txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to count all the letters from a text but I want to exclude the counting of a letter next to a space

```
from collections import Counter

text = 'in the seas and let fowl multiply in the earth \nand the evening and the mo were the fifth day \nand gd slet the earth bring forth the livngke man in our image after our likeness and let d over all the'
txt = [x for x in text if x not in '\n'] #this what i did for excluding the newline 

cc = Counter(zip(text, text[1:])).items() 
print(cc)
```

I want to remove all the pair with space - like this (('n', ' '), 4)

From this

> dict_items([(('i', 'n'), 5), (('n', ' '), 4), ((' ', 't'), 8), (('t', 'h'), 12), (('h', 'e'), 8), (('e', ' '), 10), ((' ', 's'), 2), (('s', 'e'), 1), (('e', 'a'), 3), (('a', 's'), 1), (('s', ' '), 2), ((' ', 'a'), 5), (('a', 'n'), 6), (('n', 'd'), 5), (('d', ' '), 7), ((' ', 'l'), 4), (('l', 'e'), 3), .....)

to this

> dict_items([(('i', 'n'), 5), (('t', 'h'), 12), (('h', 'e'), 8), (('s',
> 'e'), 1), (('e', 'a'), 3), (('a', 's'), 1), (('a', 'n'), 6), (('n',
> 'd'), 5), (('l', 'e'), 3), .....)

Comment: Can you please provide an minimal example with expected output.

Comment: Added the output i wanted, if i do remove the space like what i did with \n it will just become a whole block of text without spaces. Are there any other methods?

Comment: So, you want all pairs of characters from your text, as long as the pair doesn't include a space? Why do you need the pairs to count characters? Why not simply subtract the number of spaces from the length of the string?

Comment: I'm creating a markov chain transition matrix from the text based on the frequency of letters. I don't want to count the transition from a letter to a space or space to letter. And when i remove the spaces the last word last letter and the next word first letter is going to be counted, which i don't want to happen.

Answer (score 0):

The number of non-whitespace characters in a string:

```
import re

text = 'in the seas and let fowl multiply in the earth \nand the evening and the mo were the fifth day \nand gd slet the earth bring forth the livngke man in our image after our likeness and let d over all the'

no_space = re.sub('\s', '', text)
print(len(no_space))
```

Result:

```
156
```

If you need those pairs for something else:

```
pairs = list(zip(no_space, no_space[1:]))
print(pairs)
```

Result:

```
[('i', 'n'), ('n', 't'), ('t', 'h'), ('h', 'e'), ('e', 's'), ('s', 'e'), ...]
```

I'm using `re` because this covers all whitespace by removing everything that matches `\s` (including newlines, tabs, spaces, etc.). If you don't want to use `re` for some reason, and are only interested in ignoring regular spaces and newlines:

```
no_space = ''.join(c for c in text if c not in ' \n')
```